# Finding a record based on StartDate given a certain datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with two tables, Employees and JobCode.... Employees has employee info and the JobCode table has information about which jobs an Employee has and when they started.

Employee Table

| EmpID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | Bob |
| E2 | Jim |

JobCode Table

| EmpID | JobCode | Updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | JC1 | 2023-01-01 8:30:000.00 |
| E1 | JC2 | 2023-03-13 4:15:000.00 |
| E1 | JC3 | 2023-05-01 1:40:000.00 |
| E1 | JC4 | 2023-08-02 12:00:000.00 |
| E2 | JC0 | 2022-12-01 10:15:000.00 |
| E2 | JC1 | 2023-02-01 10:15:000.00 |
| E2 | JC3 | 2023-06-08 2:15:000.00 |

My goal is to pass a date (@ActDate) and it will return the current job for each Employee.  If the date is before the first Updated record, I want it to return the first job.  (Ex. for 2022-11-01 for E1, it would return JC1)

I've tried the following....

```
SELECT e.EmpID, a.JobCode 
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT
        EmpID,
        COALESCE(JobCode,'BEFORE'),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated DESC) AS mdr
    FROM [JobCode]
    WHERE Updated <= @ActDate
) a ON a.EmpID = e.EmpID
WHERE a.mdr = 1
```

This seems to get everything except for when the @ActDate is before the first Updated record.  Since there is no records returned for it, the COALESCE won't work, so I'm not sure what to do.

The expected results for 2023-03-20 is

| EmpID | JobCode |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | JC2 |
| E2 | JC1 |

The expected results for 2022-12-10 should be

| EmpID | JobCode |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | JC1 |
| E2 | JC0 |

Any ideas on how I can get this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of the window function.

You should also run the subqueries alone to see what your code actually returns

```
DECLARE @ActDate Date = '03-20-2023';
SELECT e.EmpID, a.JobCode 
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT
        EmpID,
        COALESCE(JobCode,'BEFORE') as JobCode,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated ASC) AS mdr
    FROM [JobCode]
    WHERE Updated <= @ActDate
) a ON a.EmpID = e.EmpID
WHERE a.mdr = 1
```

| EmpID | JobCode |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | JC1 |
| E2 | JC0 |

```
DECLARE @ActDate Date = '03-20-2023';
SELECT
        EmpID,
        COALESCE(JobCode,'BEFORE') as JobCode,
  Updated,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated ASC) AS mdr
    FROM [JobCode]
    WHERE Updated <= @ActDate
```

| EmpID | JobCode | Updated | mdr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | JC1 | 2023-01-01 08:30:00.000 | 1 |
| E1 | JC2 | 2023-03-13 04:15:00.000 | 2 |
| E2 | JC0 | 2022-12-01 10:15:00.000 | 1 |
| E2 | JC1 | 2023-02-01 10:15:00.000 | 2 |

```
DECLARE @ActDate Date = '03-20-2023';
SELECT e.EmpID, a.JobCode 
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT
        EmpID,
        COALESCE(JobCode,'BEFORE') as JobCode,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated DESC) AS mdr
    FROM [JobCode]
    WHERE Updated <= @ActDate
) a ON a.EmpID = e.EmpID
WHERE a.mdr = 1
```

| EmpID | JobCode |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | JC2 |
| E2 | JC1 |

```
DECLARE @ActDate Date = '03-20-2023';
SELECT
        EmpID,
        COALESCE(JobCode,'BEFORE') as JobCode,
  Updated,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated DESC) AS mdr
    FROM [JobCode]
    WHERE Updated <= @ActDate
```

| EmpID | JobCode | Updated | mdr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | JC2 | 2023-03-13 04:15:00.000 | 1 |
| E1 | JC1 | 2023-01-01 08:30:00.000 | 2 |
| E2 | JC1 | 2023-02-01 10:15:00.000 | 1 |
| E2 | JC0 | 2022-12-01 10:15:00.000 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HJLHsCuo)

## Update

You need to get the earliest jobcode and LEFT JOIN it to your query
before you join it to mplyee

```
DECLARE @ActDate Date = '12-10-2022';
WITH JobCode1 AS 
  (
SELECT j1.EmpID, j1.JobCode 
FROM (SELECT  EmpID, FIRST_VALUE(JobCode) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated ASC)  Jobcode
     FROM [JobCode]) j1
  GROUP BY j1.EmpID, j1.JobCode ),
  JobCode2 as (
  SELECT         EmpID,
        JobCode
        FROM
  (
    SELECT
        EmpID,
        JobCode,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY Updated ASC) AS mdr
    FROM [JobCode]  
    WHERE Updated <= @ActDate) j2
    WHERE mdr = 1)
    SELECT e.EmpID, jc.JobCode 
    FROM Employee e 
    JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(j2.EmpID, j1.EmpID) EmpID, COALESCE(j2.JobCode, j1.JobCode) JobCode FROM JobCode1 j1 LEFT JOIN JobCode2 j2 ON j2.EmpID =  j1.EmpID) jc ON e.EmpID = jc.EmpID
```

| EmpID | JobCode |
| --- | --- |
| E1 | JC1 |
| E2 | JC0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g47LA0UU)

Comment: I apologize if I'm mis-reading this, but using DESC gives me the required results except for the special case when the @ActDate is before the first JobCode date (for 12-10-2022... there is no records before this, so no record is returned, which is what I need help with)

Comment: you should have explained it better. I have added an update to my answer